# How to return the short version of the following && statement?

Tags: javascript

The following function returns a boolean:

```
store.checkAuth = () => {
  if (store.state.userInfo.uid && store.state.userInfo.email) return true
  else return false
}
```

I tried simplifying it like this:

```
store.checkAuth = () => {
  return store.state.userInfo.uid && store.state.userInfo.email
}
```

But realized that it tries to return the objects instead of a boolean.

What's the correct way of simplifying the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by explicitly converting the result to boolean,

```
store.checkAuth = () => {
  return !!(store.state.userInfo.uid && store.state.userInfo.email)
}
```

[Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) says that when `expr1 && expr2` executes,

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns
>   expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both
>   operands can be converted to true; otherwise, returns false.

So here in our case, the first truthy value will be returned not the boolean result that you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
store.checkAuth = () => {
  return store.state.userInfo.uid && store.state.userInfo.email ? true : false;
}
```